# How to solve the error "Empty response" in angular while uploading bulk data through nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6

[image]I'm uploading bulk data using Angular UI and nodejs backend. For 10000 records data are uploading as expected & I'm getting successful response from nodejs. But once it exceeds 10000 records, I'm getting Empty RESPONSE as an error.

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

But half of the data (10000) is getting uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

this is to do with the connection timeout. Increase the timeout value and see

Comment: I have increased the time out to 10 mins in the nodejs side, but the thing is Im getting the empty response in UI after 13000 records are getting inserted(within 3 mins). But in the backend records are keep on getting submitted. Could you please tell me, like where I need to set timeout ? @Saif Kamaal

Comment: i am not sure which client side library you are using but have a look at https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#timeout. Here you can specify the timeout period.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal implementation is that, payload to the API resource should be of lesser size to have a better performance. Instead of sending a payload of 10000 records to API, have a logic to write ~5k (number depends on the size of the individual record, reduce the same for higher size data) records as payload at a time to API. Have an iteration logic to send all the data to API with ~5k records at time.

This would not only improve performance but it will avoid the time out network errors and will have a better UX design with intermediate status of uploading been shown to the user from UI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are doing this in nodejs side. Actually the thing is,   from backend it keeps on uploading, but in the front end we are getting the error after 2 to 3 mins. Or we need to do this in front end side only like you are suggesting?

Comment: Error happens due to timeout. hence send intermediate statuses from your backend to front end of the uploading process to show statuses in UI and close the parent request. or send the request to backend in parts as suggested and show the statuses to user in UI. I would recommend the second, as you will have lesser payload data to API for each requests rather than sending 10k items in a single request.